# NextJS and useRouter locale Typescript error - Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm getting the following typescript error and I don't understand why - the solutions I've seen in other questions don't work so I clearly don't understand what is going on here

> Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.

I'm setting the language strings using locale from `useRouter next/router` which will return a string depending on the URL and by default will always return `"en-US"` from this following code;

```
  const { locale } = useRouter();
  const { pageTitle } = languageContent[locale];
```

If I hard code locale as so it resolves the error

```
  const { locale } = useRouter();
  const { pageTitle } = languageContent["en-US"];
```

`languageContent` contains all of my language strings as so;

```
const languageContent = {
    "en-US": {
        pageTitle: "Title",
    },
    "fr-FR": {
        pageTitle: "Titre",
    },
    "iw": {
        pageTitle: "כותרת",
    },
};

export default languageContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved this was to change the `languageContent` JSON to this

```
const languageContent = {
    english: {
        pageTitle: "Title",
    },
    french: {
        pageTitle: "Titre",
    },
    hebreb: {
        pageTitle: "כותרת",
    },
};
```

And then I can change the the other two lines as follows

```
const { locale } = useRouter();
  const { pageTitle } = locale === "fr-FR" ? languageContent.french : locale === "iw" ? languageContent.hebrew : languageContent.english;
```